# Multiple stores in ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am writing an enterprise-scale application with Angular and ngrx. The intention is to use Flux and ngrx throughout. For reuse and separability we require (at least) two state stores that do not interact with each other. But we do need both stores to be active at the same time, and potentially accessed from the same components.

Ngrx seems to be predicated on the assumption that there will only ever be one Store at once. Is there an approach that will allow me to have multiple Store objects (templated of course with different State objects), and have them both loaded and active at the same time?

I'm aware that 'best practice' recommends combining the stores into one. That's not viable here unless there is an entirely novel approach.

Comment: Not sure about having separate stores. You may be able to accomplish what you want by using feature state. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/api.md#feature-module-state-composition

Comment: As @bygrace stated, realize two separated `modules` then, on each of them, simply import `StoreModule.forFeature('reducerName', reducer)`. Of course, just start the `StoreModule.forRoot()` in your `app.module`.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for, both of you. Thanks very much. If either of you would like to make that an answer I would vote it up and accept. If not I'll make an answer myself.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd suggest setting up two feature states. Here are the relevant docs:
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/v5.2.0/docs/store/api.md#feature-module-state-composition

Though it isn't the same thing as having two separate stores it is the same for most practical purposes. The feature states are loaded when the module that imports `StoreModule.forFeature('featureName', reducers)` is loaded. You could do this lazy or eager. Each feature state will have access to root state so you can put common state on root state that both can access. Feature states should never reference each-other as they may not be loaded and that would negate the reason for having them.

Comment: Despite my statement that I need two stores, this is the answer I wanted. The key thing I needed is there, namely that each Store can define its Reducers, Effects, Actions and State structures entirely independently of the other stores. I'm happy to write the few lines of code to combine the different Store definitions into a single StoreModule.

Comment: I'm afraid links are no longer valid. They raise 404 errors!

Comment: @IgnacioHR Looks like it moved but I haven't used ngrx for a bit. So I can't suggest a link to a recent release but I updated the link to a release that would have been active at the time of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have created complete application for multiple stores using actions and reducers. I have uploaded zip file in github.

https://github.com/akashprince138/multiple_store

Comment: Hi Akash. Thanks for contributing. However we are looking for answers that explain rather than just links to code. If you wanted to explain how you did this in the answer (and it is significantly different from the other answer) you could than post this link as an example.