# Multiple Stores with NGRX with only one reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I know it has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409381/multiple-stores-in-ngrx), but it has't been answered directly.
I am looking to get 2+ stores of the same reducer/effects/selectors/actions.

Basically, I display some data on the page side by side, both behave exactly the same.

I am aware, I can do 2 features, `side1`, `side2`, but then I would have to duplicate all my selectors, all my actions, all my effects, all my reducers; otherwise they will collide with each other.

What is the best way to achieve this while avoiding code duplication? let's say it would be a shame if I have to adapt all the code to accept the `side` parameter for all my actions.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short - no, there's not an easy way to do it.

To do it you need to ensure that modules don't have a parent like AppModule that imports `StoreModule.forRoot`. Then you can import `StoreModule.forRoot` in every module and it will create separate stores for every node, but disadvantage in this case that you can't access other store's data.

If you want to have a single store but to affect different features with the same actions you need to implement `correlationId` pattern for all actions, reducers and effects to ensure that they won't cause data collision on each other.

Also you can do like `ngrx/data` does - access store via services instead of `actions` and `selectors`, then for every module it would be like

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserSelectorService implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        protected serviceFactory: EntityCollectionServiceFactory,
    ) {
    }

    public readonly users = this.serviceFactory.create('users');
    public readonly data$ = this.users.selectAll();

   ngOnInit() {
     this.users.load();
   }
}
```